# Getting request body as a string from API gateway, expecting JSON content

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I have recently started to create a slack slash command bot for learning purpose. I am getting the different format of request body from API gateway and nodejs app on EC2 server. I just want to get JSON format of request body from API gateway. How can get it?

Let's have a look at both the body format and serverless.yml file.

First, I have installed the serverless framework & created the serverless.yml file with the following code,

```js
service: as-serverless-slack-bot 
# NOTE: update this with your service name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

 functions:
 info:
    handler: handler.info
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: slack/info
          cors: true
```

Now, I have deployed it successfully. However, when I execute slack slash command, I receive request body in string format from API gateway,

```js
body: 'token=XXXXXX&team_id=XXXXXXXX&team_domain=XXXXXXX&channel_id=XXXXXXX&channel_name=XXXXXX&user_id=XXXXXX&user_name=XXXXXXX&command=%2Finfo&text=about+users&response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%2XXXXXXX%2XXXXXXXXXXX&trigger_id=562173962614.55XXXXXXXXX.326e28e8599XXXcacf0XXXXXa'
```

While, for the same action, I am getting JSON formatted request body in EC2 nodejs app.

```js
{
  "body": {
    "token": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "team_id": "xxxxxx",
    "team_domain": "xxxxxx",
    "channel_id": "xxxx",
    "channel_name": "xxxx",
    "user_id": "xxx",
    "user_name": "xx",
    "command": "/info",
    "text": "about users",
    "response_url": "https://hooks.slack.com/commands/x/x/x",
    "trigger_id": "560161450593.558xxxxxxxx3.3741c456xxxxx05cc6xxx62"
  }
}
```

So, how can I get request body in JSON format from API gateway?

Comment: In API Gateway, go to `integration request` -> `Body Mapping Templates` and select `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Default lambda integration is via "lambda proxy" which bypasses API Gateway's request/response transformers. You basically get the raw payload to deal with.

If you want API Gateway to do some of the work, you need to switch integration to `lambda` and configure API Gateway to accept `application/json` as a request type.

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#lambda-integration